# Define a priority for termination of K8s pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a bunch of pods running in the same cluster. Sometimes there are not enough resources and some pods need to terminate.

That's OK, but how do I set the priority of which pods are killed first?

It usually kills my most important service first :\

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [resource QoS](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/resource-qos.md).

Have you important stuff (including monitoring) specify limit=request which in turn will land them in the guaranteed QoS class.

Specifically,

> The system computes pod level requests and limits by summing up per-resource requests and limits across all containers. When request == limit, the resources are guaranteed (...)

Also, overstepping CPU limits only results in throttling, so it's more important to get memory limits (per container) right.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - in order to qualify for "Guaraneed", all of the containers need to set a limit for the same resource type? Or for all resource types?